# Spring Security, multiple http elements. Which is which?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Config which is working fine. My Spring Config uses multiple `security:http` sections.
When you define a `security:http` section, certain operations happen automagically, such as some bean definitions. One of these beans that get defined automatically, is a `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` -implementing bean.

Question: how can you identify which is which? For example I need to reference from code, via `@Autowired`, a specific authentication strategy, defined in a specific `http:security` tag; how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to have the same `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` instance in your custom bean and inside `<sec:http>`-spawned machinery is to go in the opposite direction: define `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` explicitly and inject it wherever you want, including `http` configuration:

```
<bean id="fancySessionAuthStrategy" class="com.fancy.FancySessionAuthStrategy">
    ...
</bean>

<sec:http ...>
    <sec:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="fancySessionAuthStrategy"/>
    ...
</sec:http>
```

The only problem here is that you will have to manually build that strategy bean definition.

An example can be found in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/session-mgmt.html

Comment: I'm trying to avoid defining my own, because I'm not very familiar with those mechanisms. But if I don't find something else, I'll probably go down that route.